# JTextField needs to get blank and also make case insensitive search

Tags: java, swing

I have two problems while searching for a text in a JTable:

1) For example, in JTextField I must initially have a 'Search Text' in transparent manner and if I click on it, the textfield must become blank and we can enter text there. How to achieve this in Java Swing?

2) My search coding is,

```
private void search8()
{
String target8 = sear8.getText();
for(int row = 0; row < table8.getRowCount(); row++)
for(int col = 0; col < table8.getColumnCount(); col++)
{
String next8 = (String)table8.getValueAt(row, col);
if(next8.equals(target8))
{
showSearchResults(row, col);
return;
}
}
```

But it is case-sensitive. I want it to be case-insensitive search. Where should I make changes in this? Also, for eg, if there is a text 'abc' and now I need to type the entire word 'abc'. Is there any way such that, if I type 'a' or 'bc' it would take me to that cell?

Kindly guide me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a custom paint method

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    super.paintComponent(g);

    String label = getLabel();
    if (label != null && (getText() == null || getText().length() == 0)) {

        Insets insets = getInsets();
        int width = getWidth() - (insets.left + insets.right);
        int height = getHeight() - (insets.top + insets.bottom);

        // This buffer should be created when the label is changed
        // or the size of the component is changed...
        BufferedImage buffer = ImageUtilities.createCompatibleImage(width, height, Transparency.TRANSLUCENT);
        Graphics2D g2d = buffer.createGraphics();

        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.setColor(getForeground());
        g2d.setFont(getFont());

        FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();

        Composite comp = g2d.getComposite();
        g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.25f));

        int textHeight = fm.getHeight();

        int x = insets.left;
        int y = ((height - textHeight) / 2) + fm.getAscent();

        g2d.drawString(label, 0, y);

        g2d.dispose();

        g.drawImage(buffer, insets.left, insets.top, this);

    }

}
```

I've had some issues with it running on MacOS, hence the use of `BufferedImage` but it should work fine.

I typically wait until the user has typed in the field before clearing the label, but you could use a focus listener and flag to trigger the process instead

**UPDATED with FOCUS LISTENER**

```
public class MyTextField extents JTextField implements FocusListener {

    private boolean hasFocus = false;

    public void addNotify() {
        super.addNotify();
        addFocusListener(this);
    }

    public void removeNotify() {
        removeFocusListener(this);
        super.removeNotify();
    }

    public void focusGained(FocusEvent evt) {

        hasFocus = true;

    }

    public void focusLost(FocusEvent evt) {

        hasFocus = false;

    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        String label = getLabel();
        if (!hasFocus && label != null && (getText() == null || getText().length() == 0)) {
            // As above...
        }
    }
}
```

Or something to that effect

Comment: Thanks for that, Sir. I get an error that focus listener can't be applied to that Sir. I have already used an actionListener on that textfield. So, is focuslistener not working because of that?

Comment: Without your code, it's difficult to tell.  From memory, `JTextField`s don't implement `FocusListener` so you need to implement that yourself.

Comment: @Gomathi I've updated the answer with an additional example, implementing the `FocusListener`.  In my code I use something similar to provide `selectAll` on `focusGained`

Comment: Thank you so much, Sir. It worked. Also, for eg, if there is a text 'abc' and now I need to type the entire word 'abc'. Is there any way such that, if I type 'a' or 'bc' it would take me to that cell?

Comment: Sir, can you please tell me the changes I have to make in the Search coding I've provided, so that it recursively checks for successive texts also. Now it's showing only the first occurrence of the text.

Answer (score 3):

**1.** Create a `hint` for your JTextView. See this example http://code.google.com/p/xswingx/

**2.** Use `equalsIgnoreCase( )` for comparison with **case-Insensitivity...**

**////////////////////EDITED PART//////////////////////**

**3.** If you **dont want to** implement a **hint** as i mentioned in point 1, **then use** `FocusListener`.

**Eg:**

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField("A TextField");
textField.addFocusListener(this);
public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {

        textField = "" ;
}
```

**See this for more details:**

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/focuslistener.html

Comment: Thank you so much, Sir. My Case-insensitive problem ended. Is there any way for achieving partial text search, as I've explained in my question,Sir?

Comment: Thanks for that, Sir. I get an error that focus listener can't be applied to that Sir. I have already used an actionListener on that textfield. So, is focuslistener not working because of that?

Comment: @Gomathi as I stated in response to the same question, `JTextField`'s to support the `FocusListener` interface, you will need to implement that your self.

Comment: @KumarVivekMitra +1 for the reference to xswingx.  I like, I like a lot

Answer (score 1):

For the case sensitive part, you can use [`String.compareToIgnoreCase()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareToIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Also, for eg, if there is a text 'abc' and now I need to type the entire word 'abc'. Is there any way such that, if I type 'a' or 'bc' it would take me to that cell?

Answer (score 1):

You should use    `next8.equalsIgnoreCase(target8)`   in place of `next8.equals(target8)`  for your search to be case insensitive.

Comment: Also, for eg, if there is a text 'abc' and now I need to type the entire word 'abc'. Is there any way such that, if I type 'a' or 'bc' it would take me to that cell?

Comment: @Gomathi Try String.contains(CharSequence)  method.. may be it could help you with what you want...

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked! But I have one more problem. With the coding I've provided, it shows only the first instance of the text. Is there any way to find successive findings also?

Answer (score 1):

yeah - I'm aware that developers love to re-invent the wheel :-) Biased me prefers to use my [favourite framework SwingX](http://swingx.java.net) which already has all necessary building blocks:

- automatic search support working the same way across all collection components
- WYMIWYS (what-you-match-is-what-you-see), that is it uses the actual string representation in the renderering component instead of a dumb toString
- search components are pluggable

That's the theory, at least, so on to eating my own dog food: the default findbar - that's the component to use for incremental search, that is searching the target while typing - uses a plain text field instead of the required prompt field. A custom implementation:

```
/**
 * A custom JXFindBar which uses a JXTextField instead of a plain as super.
 */ 
public static class PromptSearchBar extends JXFindBar {

    /**
     * Overridden to replace the plain text field in super
     * with a JXTextField (which supports prompts).
     */
    @Override
    protected void initComponents() {
        super.initComponents();
        searchField = new JXTextField() {
            @Override
            public Dimension getMaximumSize() {
                Dimension superMax = super.getMaximumSize();
                superMax.height = getPreferredSize().height;
                return superMax;
            }

        };
        searchField.setColumns(getSearchFieldWidth());
        ((JXTextField) searchField).setPrompt(getUIString(SEARCH_FIELD_LABEL));
    }

    /**
     * Overridden to update the prompt in addition to super
     */
    @Override
    protected void updateLocaleState(Locale locale) {
        super.updateLocaleState(locale);
        ((JXTextField) searchField).setPrompt(getUIString(SEARCH_FIELD_LABEL, locale));
    }
    /**
     * Overridden to not add the search label.
     */
    @Override
    protected void build() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout(SwingConstants.LEADING));
        add(searchField);
        add(findNext);
        add(findPrevious);
    }

}
```

Installing in custom code:

```
SearchFactory factory = new SearchFactory() {

    @Override
    public JXFindBar createFindBar() {
        return new PromptSearchBar();
    }

};
SearchFactory.setInstance(factory);
factory.setUseFindBar(true);
```

That's it - focus a JXTable, JXTree, JXList, ... press ctr-f and type away in the searchfield: the next matching cell will be highlighted.

Comment: Sir, I need some clarification reg implemntation. Should I include any package for this?

Comment: forgot the link to SwingX - now it's there. BTW: better not assume any gender ... I might feel offended ... :-)

Comment: oh..I'm sorry. Btw, what I did is, I included this class in my program and called the second part(installing the custom code) from the first class, but I get error in identifiers in `SearchFactory.setInstance(factory);
factory.setUseFindBar(true);`

Comment: no problem :-) don't - the SearchFactory is a application-scope singleton, it should be configured in application scope, not in findbar instance scope. Though I don't quite see how that might trigger an error ... you might consider asking a new question with a SSCCE demonstrating the error

Comment: oh...Is there any way to implement this in normal JTextField instead of this? :-(